# Swagger Unknown response type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I' was trying get simple JSON result via Swagger API but I cannot see body of JSON. I'm getting error "Unknown response type"

[image]

**DashboardController.cs**

```
Web.API.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/dashboards")]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DbContext context;

        public DashboardController(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Describe this method here. 
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDashboard(int id)
        {
            var entity = await context.Dashboards
                .Include(d => d.DashboardType)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == id);
            return Ok(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what's problem ? I've added  [Produces("application/json")] on Controller manually, tested it Mozzila and Chrome and the same thing.

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace Web.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Test API", Description ="Swagger core test API" });
                var xmlPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Test.Web.API.xml";
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });

            services.AddTransient<DatabaseDeployer>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DatabaseDeployer deployer)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Core API");
                });
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
            app.UseMvc();
            deployer.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well how would Swagger know what your method returns?

Either make sure it can find out what you return through your method declaration:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<DashBoardData> GetDashboard(int id)
```

Or if you want to keep the IActionResult, at least annotate what it's going to be:

```
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(DashBoardData), "Successful Request.")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDashboard(int id)
```

Assuming `DashBoardData` is the class that is returned from your query.

Comment: Did you take a tool like Fiddler to have a look what is actually returned?

Answer (score -2):

I've resolved this. Problem was with this part in Startup.cs file

```
  app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
```

when I delete it I got json response result and works fine.